# How do you make an image into a link in HTML?

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I want to make an image so that when you click on it it will take you somewhere.
What is the coding for this?

Answer (score 9):

Wrap the img tag in an anchor tag

```
<a href='someurl'>
  <img src='someImage' />
</a>
```