# How do I add a link (href) to the image

Tags: html, css

I want to make the image a link so that when you click on the image it takes you to the link.

I tried the anchor link but that doesn't work. Below is my HTML and CSS code.

```css
.ideas-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25rem, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.title-heading{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10rem;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    background-color: white;
}

.title-heading h1{
    font-family: 'Aldrich', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: .5rem 0 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.title-heading p{
    text-transform: none;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

.idea-grid-item{
    height: 50rem;
    width: 50rem;
    padding: 5rem;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.idea-grid-item{
    content:"";
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(49,24,131,0.9) 0%, rgba(72,56,149,0.8) 100%);
    z-index: -1;
}

.idea-grid-item p{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.idea-grid-item a{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="ideas-grid">
           <!--Idea grid item 1-->
           <div class="idea-grid-item number-1">
           <p>
           </p>
           <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/B5NVsqhhp9O/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the ```<div class="idea-grid-item number-1">``` within an anchor tag. Like this ```<a href="your/target/"><div class="idea-grid-item number-1"></div></a>```

Comment: @Eisenheim thank you so much you were the only one that had a correct answer i didnt think of that thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm happy to hear that worked :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make an image into a link in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561759/how-do-you-make-an-image-into-a-link-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the entire image to be a link, wrap it in an `<a>` element like this:

```html
<a href="http://yoursite.com">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://sitelink.xyz"><img src="image.jpg"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```