# Can you paste an image as a link to another page

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, copy, paste

I want to be able to paste a link to users directing them to my home page but instead of it being just a link I want to paste and share the logo pic so when users click on the logo pic they are taken to my home page - I'm just trying to make my links look good is there a way to do this?

I am limited to basic HTML (still learning the ropes) so please be gentle :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is where users usually encourage you to do more research, as [this question is answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561759/how-do-you-make-an-image-into-a-link-in-html)

Comment: sorry Odin but it doesn't answer my question. My question is about copying a pic with a link on it and then pasting it any were i choose so users can click the pic and visit my web page.

Answer (score 3):

As basic as it can get with HTML:

```html
<a href="link-url-here">
    <img src="image-url-here">
</a>
```

[Here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/tp5qu3zx/).

The picture in this fiddle can be selected, copied then pasted to a lot of places i.e. an email body. But please note that many places probably won't support the hyperlink functionality that you're looking for. And some will (I just tested successfully with Gmail)

And welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: hi odin ur html code works (thanks) but how do i copy paste it for users to use?

Comment: Lovely. Not quite sure what you mean by "copy paste it for users to use". I would probably  need a more specific use case to help you with that.

Comment: it works the same way you copy and paste a link i just want the link to be a picture

Comment: I updated my answer. Please let me know if I hit it

Comment: thanks odin that worked a treat i used it in messenger which is were i do most of my work and it worked great ur a star :) THANKS for your help

Comment: i was premature in my response Odin but i was right saying ur link worked but as soon as i remove the www from my link i run into problems - i can copy/paste the image no bother but when i click it all i get is a picture of the link - here's the code I'm using -                                                                                                        
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>
<a href="https://www.bng59.com/Home.html">
<img src="https://www.bng59.com/copypastetest.png" width="200" height="130">
</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: No problem, just include it ```<a href="https://www.bng59.com/Home.html">
  <img src="https://www.bng59.com/copypastetest.png">
</a>```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="link to your homepage"><img src="https://link-to-image.com"/></a>
```

Something like this?

Comment: thanks luk_9900 i got my answer from odin